# Can't connect to AmazonMQ using Symfony messenger component

Tags: symfony, amqp, amazon-mq

I'm having problems using the messenger component with amqp in AmazonMQ. When run `php bin/console messenger:setup-transports` I receive this message:

```
Could not connect to the AMQP server. Please verify the provided DSN.
Library error: connection closed unexpectedly - Potential login failure.
```

The user credentials are correct, and the provided DSN appears to be fine (I can connect to a RabbitMQ server with a similar configuration without any problem), but fails miserabily with AmazonMQ.

I had searched in stackoverflow and forums, but I couldn't find a solution nor a similar problem.

Has anyone faced similar problem?

Comment: possibly a permission / security group problem?

Comment: Hi @Jakumi. I already checked that the security group permission is correct, and  I can reach the DSN via telnet.

Comment: iam/ec2 are the only ideas i have, but I'm not an aws pro. have you checked the aws support forums too?